# JQuery hover over complete div

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="card">
    <img src="test.jpg" />
    <p class="alt-text">Some Text</p>
    <p class="actions" style="display: none;">Some Buttons</p>
</div>
```

And the following JS code

```
$(".card").on("mouseover", function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.find(".actions").toggle();
    $t.find(".alt-text").toggle();
});
```

If I hover over the Card-Div, the text under the image should change from "Some Text" to "Some Buttons".

Ok, if I hover over the image, its working, but if I go some pixels down (to the paragraph), the hover event is triggered again and the text switches again.

My question is: Why is the hover event triggert again and how can I prevent this?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I am so stupid.

The problem was, that if I toggle the paragraph, the paragraph gets hidden. Now the div isn't that height anymore, so I leave the div for some microseconds. But afterwards the second paragraph is shown, and the cards-div height becomes the old height. So the hover event is triggered again.

Now we have an endless loop :D

Comment: if possible please provide example on FiDDLE

Comment: try `mouseenter` instead.

Comment: event bubbling possibly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [mouseenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter), [mouseover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseover) is a bubbling event which will be fired when you change over from one descendant to another one.

```
$(".card").on("mouseenter", function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.find(".actions").toggle();
    $t.find(".alt-text").toggle();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1c2v9574/)

---

If you want to switch back also then use the hover() method

```
$(".card").hover(function (e) {
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.find(".actions").toggle(e.type == 'mouseenter');
    $t.find(".alt-text").toggle(e.type == 'mouseleave');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1c2v9574/2/)

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1c2v9574/6/), you can see how the mouseover is getting triggered by the descendant elements

Comment: Thank you. This also works: $(".card").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.find(".actions").toggle();
    $t.find(".alt-text").toggle();
});

Answer (score 2):

You can use `hover` event as shown below

```
$(function(){
 $(".card").on("hover", function(){
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.find(".actions").toggle();
    $t.find(".alt-text").toggle();
 });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/jspkadLg/1/)**